# Grey text appear white with outline in android device

Tags: android, text, colors, textview

anyone has had this issue?
I am making an android app and my text within textview is a light grey. It is not very visible, but that is the effect I want.
When I look at my emulator it is fine, but when i upload the app to my android device, the text is corrected and now appears as white with a black outline.
I don't want this. I want the light grey color...

here is the actual code for the full layout for those asking:

> xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
> xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
> android:id="@+id/activity_splash_screen"
> android:layout_width="match_parent"
> android:layout_height="match_parent"
> android:padding="20dp"
> android:layout_gravity="center"
> android:background="#ffffff"
> >
>
> ```
> <TextView
>     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:text="some text here"
>     android:textColor="#888888" /> </RelativeLayout>
> ```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is the code above the actual code that you are using for your TextView, or is that a simplification?

Comment: it is the actual code. look I even added pictures from android studio and the emulator running and also screenshots from my android device. It is just the splash screen but anywhere else on my app its the same thing. Any text that is too pale suddenly changes like this!

Comment: I have a motorola Moto e5 play, android 8.0.0

Comment: Since also your battery level and your clock display text are white with a black outline, I assume this is something at your system's level. Do you have some high contrast accessibility turned ON or any custom system-wide UI modifications? Or is it just a default theme like that?

Answer (score 1):

In the comments, [@Ma3x asked in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70614646/grey-text-appear-white-with-outline-in-android-device/70615380#comment124830190_70614646):

> Since also your battery level and your clock display text are white with a black outline, I assume this is something at your system's level. Do you have some high contrast accessibility turned ON or any custom system-wide UI modifications? Or is it just a default theme like that? –

That gave me the hint I needed. In *Settings* > *accessibility* > *High Contrast*.

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Instead, **[accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)** that you found most helpful. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/30758144)

Comment: i cant accept the anwser... it wont let me, thats why i responded with thank you

Comment: @Robert: It was clumsy wording, but it's totally acceptable to "elevate" a comment to an answer, since you can't otherwise accept a comment. I have made an [edit] to this answer to improve how the source suggestion is referenced.